Maven custom property overridden despite specifying in command-line
Problem Description:
I have a Maven project (pom.xml) where I define a build-number property in the  section:
<properties>
    ...
    <build-number>1</build-number> <!-- Default value -->
</properties>


This is again referenced in
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalProperties>
                                <build.number>${build-number}</build.number>
                            </additionalProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

When I execute the Maven build command like this:
mvn clean install -Dbuild-number=128 -DskipTests
The build.properties file still shows build.build.number=1 instead of build.build.number=128
Tried removing the default value and kept it empty, its accepting the value. But that property can't be kept as empty
